# local port showed on netstats and port logged by apache not same

Tags: networking, apache-http-server, port

I want to log the client ip and port on my apache server.

my apache config:

```
LogFormat "%v:%p [%h]:%{remote}p %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
```

after i used my browser visit the site, the apache logged as following:

```
www.site.domain:443 [218.79.42.250]:60496 - - [30/Oct/2019:22:22:21 +0800] "GET /index.php?r=site/user-is-active HTTP/1.1" 200 646 "https://www.mathcrowd.cn/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36"
www.site.domain:443 [218.79.42.250]:60496 - - [30/Oct/2019:22:22:22 +0800] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 1479 "https://www.mathcrowd.cn/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36"
```

`218.79.42.250`, which my client ip, logged correctly.

but the client port logged is not same as the local client showed by `netstat`.

```
  TCP    192.168.1.191:50048    site-ip:443     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.191:50049    site-ip:443     ESTABLISHED
```

furthermore, is it possible to record client's original ip `192.168.1.191` and port `55048,55049` from the apache server?

Answer (score 0):

Probably your router is set with standard NAT settings.

Usually it includes [PAT](https://www.cisco.com/assets/sol/sb/RV320_Emulators/RV320_Emulator_v1-1-0-09/help/Setup13.html).

It means your router is replacing not only the IP, but the ports too.

You can check your router NAT table to see the current translations

Comment: so, is it possible to log the original IP(192.168.1.191) and original port(50048,50049) from my apache server?

Comment: Maybe you can cancel the PAT in your router settings. If it's not an advanced router there is good chance you can't.
But why do you even care about the local port of the client? It is randomly created by the OS.

Comment: Maybe for security reason, to find the identification of the device? So, I want to record more detailed information from the client, not only a public ip address.

Comment: You can't identify a device with info you don't have. You can't identify a router, because each request can come from a different source port. You can ask a different question to solve the specific issue you have about security / identification, but for sure - source port is not the right way.